# Laravel Socialite Google Login

Tags: laravel, google-signin, laravel-socialite

This is just a general question about Oauth2. Say I use Laravel Socialite to add a google login during development phase. The client_ID and Secret both matches my google console ones. But when it comes to make the website public and other people wants to login via their google account. How can they login without knowing their own client_ID and secret.

Comment: What do you mean by **How can they login without knowing their own client_ID and secret?**. Who's **they**? And the user don't need to know the id or secret. Please clarify.

Comment: oh nvm I just realized that people can login with their respective google account even if the client id and secret are set to be mine. My confusion was that since those credentials were mine, I was assuming that the Oauth2 would only recognize my account. It was a misunderstanding from my part.